# What is the best way to sync Postgres and ElasticSearch?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch

I have the choice to Sync ES with latest changes on my Postgres DB

1- Postgres Listen / Notify :

I should create a `trigger` -> use `pg_notify` -> and create listener in a separated service.

2- Async queries to ES :

I can update ElasticSearch asynchronously after a change on DB. ie:

`model.save().then(() => {model.saveES() }).catch()`

Which one will scale best ?

PS: We tried `zombodb` in production but it doesn’t goes well, it slows down the production.

Comment: looking for something like this https://github.com/toptal/chewy

Comment: @user3775217 this will help on bulk import, but i don't need that.
I need real time sync between what is happening in PostgresDB and ES.

Our Postgres ( the size is ~ 1 TB ) become slow, a lot of cron jobs/analytics for machine learning, etc. What we do is to add/update/delete to the DB and Read from ES. So ES need be sync on real time. and that won't help. 

is it clear ? ( my english is really bad :/ )

Answer (score 9):

as you are asking for the ways, I assume you want to know the possibilities to apply the better architecture, I would like you to propose an advice given by confluent:

[image]

[image]

here https://www.confluent.io/blog/bottled-water-real-time-integration-of-postgresql-and-kafka/

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you consider https://github.com/debezium/debezium. It has Postgresql support and implements the `change capture` model proposed in other posts instead of the `dual write` model.

debezium benefits:

- low latency change streaming
- stores changes in a replicated log for durability
- emits only write events (creates, updates, deletes) which can be consumed and piped into other systems.

**UPD.** [Here is a simple github repository](https://github.com/egorzaremba/sync-postgresql-with-elasticsearch-example), which shows how it works